# MVC 4 Matching application user profile with contact table record

Tags: sql, asp.net-mvc-4, matching

I have a similar issue with my HR database.

I am using Google ID login - UserProfile table for application users and Contact table to store all the employees.

Because the users will also have access to their records (update their personal details) and will submit request for holidays, I need to match the UserProfile.UserProfileID with Contact.ContactID.

The login - when a new UserProfileID is created and the creation of a new contact (by the HR department) should mach also.

Any advice?

Bellow is the model for UserProfile and Contact.
 UserProfile

```
public class UserProfileViewModel
{
    [Key]
    public int ID { get; set; }
    [Display(Name = "User Name")]
    public string UserName { get; set; }
    [Display(Name = "First Name")]
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    [Display(Name = "Last Name")]
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    [DisplayFormat(NullDisplayText = "", DataFormatString = "{0:dd/MM/yyyy hh:mm tt}")]
    public DateTime? LastLogon { get; set; }
    [Display(Name = "Roles")]
    public string[] UserRoles { get; set; }
    public string DisplayName { get; set; }
}
```

Contact

```
public class Contact
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public int? TitleID { get; set; }
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    public DateTime? DOB { get; set; }
    public int? GenderID { get; set; }
    public int? CategoryID { get; set; }
    public int? SiteID { get; set; }
```

....
}

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

Managed to find a way to solve the issue.
Modified the UserProfile table by adding a new field called ContactID and then when a new contact is created, the UserProfile is also created and the Contact.ID is passed to UserProfile.ContactID.